# Typescript compiles into Javascript wrong?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, tsc

I'm trying to connect to MongoDB in my Node app using Typescript.

This line of code:

```
const MongoClient = mongoDb.MongoClient;
```

Compiles into this line of code:

```
const MongoClient = mongodb_1.default.MongoClient;
```

Throwing this error:
**TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'MongoClient')**

Removing the ".default." in the compiled code makes it run.

I've tried messing with **package.json** as well as **tsconfig.json**
Namely the **esModuleInterop** and **allowSyntheticDefaultImports**
but nothing works.

Comment: Is because of the way you import or require `mongoDb`. You imported the module as a default but there's no default there. There's some options in the `tsconfig.json` file for this (I don't remember exactly the option, maybe something about "interop", but I encourage you to read all the options there in the online doc, as you may find nice ones, like typing options for binds or typing options for nulls), or you can change the way you import the default. Instead of `import mongoDb from "mongodb"` (is a default) do `import * as mongoDb from "mongodb"` or `import { MongoClient } from "mongodb"`

Comment: That was it, can't believe i've been stuck at this error for like 2 hours. Thank you!

Comment: {
  "compilerOptions": {
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": false
  }
}
 As @JorgeFuentesGonzález said , the tsconfig.json options would be.

Comment: `import * as mongoDb` is the way to go.  My advice is to avoid adding anything to the configuration file if you can.  BTW if your tooling was working, you would have received an error before you were able to compile.